# How do I send Tradingview chart snapshots to twitter using python/pinescript?

Tags: python, twitter, pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I want to send tradingview chart snapshots to twitter. I have a screener i made (using pinescript) which shows buy/sell signals on different pairs.

Whenever there's a new signal on a pair, I want it to take a snapshot of that particular pair and send it to twitter. How do I do this with python and/or pinescript?